# How to solve AWS API gateway timeout error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-http-api, aws-rest-api

I have react webapp to make HTTP calls using **fetch API**.

Calls go to **HTTP API gateway** which is attached to a lambda function. Lambda fn is nothing but contains my entire node/express app (backend). Please note I have only one big lambda fn with node/express code.

Currently it works fine but problem comes when I hit certain APIs, certain APIs might take more than 30 seconds. In such case, **API gateway** shows **timeout** and sends `internal server error` msg to the client.

**Yes, I know there are several options to over come timeout issue**.

1. **Use Websocket API gateway**. I don't know if this is right solution as I have to make changes in React (Front-end) code. Basically connect to socket and then wait for response etc. I don't want to make such changes in the existing  implementation.
2. **Use step function**: People claim using step fn, 30 seconds timeout issues can be avoided but HOW? I don't seem to find any right example. Can some pls help to understand this concept how step fn works with API gateway and lambda. Will this even resolve the problem that I face ?

Or pls tell me any other feasible solution if you have.

Comment: A Lambda monolith - that's a new one for me.  Have you considered just a small EC2?  Depending on what the API gateway does (i.e. authentication) you may need to pull a bit of code into the application on the EC2.  But you can have a very long lived connection.  It's not perfect - you now need to maintain the server.  But, depending on your needs, a t3.small runs about USD $15/month.  There are smaller/cheaper ones and incredibly more expensive ones too.

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway enforces a strict timeout limit of 30 seconds, within which responses must be returned.
To ensure compliance with this constraint, it is essential to streamline your responses and minimize processing times.

Well-designed APIs typically deliver responses within milliseconds to a few seconds, as prolonged response times can indicate suboptimal API practices.

> Use step function: People claim using step fn, 30 seconds timeout issues can be avoided but HOW? I don't seem to find any right example. Can some pls help to understand this concept how step fn works with API gateway and lambda. Will this even resolve the problem that I face ?

1. For requests requiring extensive processing or longer execution times, consider **decoupling** the computational tasks.
   Employ an **asynchronous processing model** where the API immediately returns a success status, while a backend worker or service processes the request separately.
2. If you have any retrieval operations implement caching mechanisms to expedite data access and diminish response times. **Caching frequently requested data can significantly improve performance for GET requests.**
3. If the constraints of API Gateway do not align with your requirements, **Consider alternatives like EC2 with a reverse proxy or ELB for flexibility.** One such option is to deploy a lightweight EC2 instance configured as a reverse proxy or utilize an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) to interface with your backend.
4. Tasks that are too demanding for traditional API models, offload them to a worker-based architecture or leverage AWS Batch and EC2 for more resource-intensive processing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Application Load Balance, it can interactive with lambda function and set timeout as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You should try increasing the timing of the lambda function and the api. gateway.

**For lambda,**

1. Go to the Lambda Function
2. Go to configuration
3. Then in General Configuration, you can edit and change the default timeout settings

[image: Lambda Configuration]

**For API Gateway,**

1. Go to Api Gateway and select the api
2. Click on the method (POST, GET)
3. In Integraton Request tab, you can edit the timeout

[image: Api Gateway]

Comment: It can't go beyond 29s.